# onPostExecute does not properly start activity

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, mapbox

I am using AsyncTask to run information to and from my online mySQL database. I am then using JSON parsing to add the information from the database as a marker on my MapBox map. Currently when a user uploads a new marker (`washroom` in the code) it uploads the information to the database, then runs the `onPostExecute` method and goes back to the `MapsActivity.java`. `MapsActivity.java` should reload the map and display the newly added marker but it doesn't; it only displays the markers that where added before adding the new one. If you close and open the app the markers are updated, displaying all the markers including the new one! Any help would be appreciated!

**Part of MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {


private MapView mapView;
private MapboxMap map;
private ImageButton locationToggle;
private LocationServices locationServices;
private String json_string;
private JSONObject jsonObject;
private JSONArray jsonArray;

public static String WASHROOMINFO;

public static String CURRENT_LOCATION;

private static final int PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.accessToken));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    //getting location services
    locationServices = com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationServices.getLocationServices(MapsActivity.this);

    //onClick to go to add washroom activity
    findViewById(R.id.addWashroom).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (CURRENT_LOCATION != null) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddWashroom.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You Must Turn on User Location Before Adding a Washroom!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    });

    //washrooms have not been loaded in yet
    if (!BackgroundTask.WASHROOMS_LOADED) {
        //getting database info
        String method = "getWashroom";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getBaseContext());
        backgroundTask.execute(method);
        finish();

    }

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            //when map is ready assign mapboxMap variable
            map = mapboxMap;

            //Washroom loading has been requested and JSON data is ready
            if (BackgroundTask.WASHROOMS_LOADED) {

                //Getting JSON data from intent
                json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
                try {
                    //new JSON object from JSON data
                 jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                    //gets JSON array from JSON object
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

                    //Marker list for buffering markers
                    List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

                    //do this for all markers!
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        //Single JSON object of single marker
                        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Dividing location field into lat & lng
                        String latlng = JO.getString("location");
                        String[] latlngSplit = latlng.split(" , ",2);
                        double lat = Double.valueOf(latlngSplit[0]);
                      double lng = Double.valueOf(latlngSplit[1]);


                        //adding marker
                        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .title(JO.getString("name"))
                               .setSnippet(JO.getString("price"))
                               .position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                        );

                        //add marker to markers list.
                        markers.add(marker);

                    }

                    BackgroundTask.WASHROOMS_LOADED = false;

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    });

    locationToggle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.location_toggle);
    locationToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (map != null) {
                //toggle GPS when clicking show location button
                toggleGps(!map.isMyLocationEnabled());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**BackgroundTask (AsyncTask)**

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context ctx;
public static boolean WASHROOMS_LOADED;
private String JSON_STRING;
private String json_string;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx.getApplicationContext();


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
String add_url = "http://appart-software.com/add_washroom.php";
String get_url = "http://appart-software.com/get_washroom.php";
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("addWashroom")) {

        String location = params[1];
        String name = params[2];
        String price = params[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(add_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("WClocation","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(location,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("WCname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("WCprice","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(price,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();
            httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
            return "Washroom Added!";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //You want to get washroom info
    } else if (method.equals("getWashroom")){

        try {

            URL url = new URL(get_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            //Return JSON formatted info
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result.equals("Washroom Added!")) {

        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        WASHROOMS_LOADED = false;


    } else {

        //setting result as a movable string
        json_string = result;

        //intent and sending JSON data
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MapsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("json_data",json_string);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);

        WASHROOMS_LOADED = true;


    }
}
}
```

If you need anymore of my code, I would be happy to show some more.

Comment: look into overriding `onNewIntent` or else intent data does not update.

Comment: In your `startActivity()`, the `intent` you are providing will basically create a new instance of your `MapActivity`, therefore, you are getting this result. You can solve it by creating an `interface` b/w these two classes and interacting using it methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting new marker on reopening the app because you are getting database info in your `onCreate()` method which is triggered only on start of activity. Try getting database info either when location changes or try overriding `onNewIntent` method. To override `onNewIntent` first set `launchmode` of your activity to `singleTop` in manifest.